# Laravelの”Breeze”でパスワードのみのログイン機能は作れますか｜Is it possible to create a password-only login function by customizing Laravel's authentication library Breeze?

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

現在、とある既存サービスのリプレイス進めており、
そのサービスではクライアントごとに各管理画面にログインさせる構造となっています。

既存サービスでは、各クライアントはログインIDを保有しておらずパスワードのみで認証しているため、一旦パスワードのみでログインさせ、その後クライアント自身でIDを設定させる構成を検討しています。

既存サービスは約10年前にFuel PHPで開発されており、セキュリティの脆弱性などの観点から、今回Laravel10でリプレイスが決定しました。

開発FWなども異なり以前のソースコードはあまり参考にできそうになく、
Breezeを使用してこのような機構が可能かどうか、可能であれば留意点をご教示いただけますと幸いです。

We are currently in the process of replacing an existing service,
The service has a structure that allows each client to log in to each management screen.

In the existing service, each client does not have a login ID, but only a password for authentication,
We are considering a structure that allows clients to log in with a password only and then set their own IDs.

The existing service was developed using Fuel PHP about 10 years ago,
Due to security vulnerabilities, we have decided to replace it with Laravel 10.

The development FW was different, and the previous source code was not very useful,
We would appreciate it if you could tell us if such a mechanism is possible using Breeze, and if so, what we need to keep in mind.

開発環境：PHP8.2.0、Laravel10.1、MAMP

Comment: 当サイトは日本語でのやり取りを前提としているため、英語の併記は不要です。英語で質問したい場合には英語版への投稿をお願いします。